# Can't figured out json formating

Tags: json

I have a json file (see below).

```
{ "data" : [ "my/path/example",
             "my/another/path" ]
}
```

I think it's an array. And I want to know is it valid json file or not?

Comment: [JSON validator](http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/); yes, it is a valid JSON file (the `data` param is an array, you are correct).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's valid JSON.

The value it represents is an object, not an array. The object has one property, whose key is `"data"`. The value of that property is an array of strings.